# Is there a way to filter Eventlog dynamically?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a PowerShell script which is executed by an event.
This PowerShell Script should then run :

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Logname='security';ID=$instanceID} -MaxEvents 1
```

to get the Event whicht triggerd de PS Script.

So Far so good, as soon as I have this event, I want to send an email. This mail should contain some content from the event message.

For Example: Event ID 4720 (A User Account was created)
The user account xx was created by xx at xx time.

Now I have roundabout 10 Event IDs to which I want to respond with an Email. These Event IDs have differences in the Message.

Is there a dynamic way to do this?

I tried the following thing:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]$instanceID
)

#$instanceIDs = @(4661,4662,5139,5136,5137,5138,5139,5141,4720,4722,4723,4724,4725,4726,4738,4740,4767,4780,4781,4794,5376,5377,4741,4742,4743,4727,4728,4729)
$event = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Logname='security';ID=$instanceID} -MaxEvents 1


Function EventIDxxx{
    Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Logname='security';ID=$instanceID} -MaxEvents 1 |
        Select-Object -Property timecreated,
        @{label='username';expression={$_.properties[0].value}},
        @{label='computername';expression={$_.properties[1].value}}
}
```

But i have to create for each Event a new function. 
Does someone have an idea ?

Thank you very much

---

**Edit **

I would like to have a Powershell script which reads out the message of the event and writes me the parts I need into variables.

```
A user account was created.

Subject:
    Security ID:        Contoso\Conlil
    Account Name:       Conlil
    Account Domain:     Contoso
    Logon ID:       0x1468731E

New Account:
    Security ID:        Contoso\ASD
    Account Name:       ASD
    Account Domain:     Contoso

Attributes:
    SAM Account Name:   ASD
    Display Name:       wSDSAD D. DSA
    User Principal Name:    ASD@Contoso.com
    Home Directory:     -
    Home Drive:     -
    Script Path:        -
    Profile Path:       -
    User Workstations:  -
    Password Last Set:  <never>
    Account Expires:        <never>
    Primary Group ID:   513
    Allowed To Delegate To: -
    Old UAC Value:      0x0
    New UAC Value:      0x15
    User Account Control:   
        Account Disabled
        'Password Not Required' - Enabled
        'Normal Account' - Enabled
    User Parameters:    -
    SID History:        -
    Logon Hours:        <value not set>

Additional Information:
    Privileges      -
```

For Example in this Event i want to have
 1. Username and Domain of Creator
 2. Name of created Account
 3. Domain of created Account
 4. Email of Created Account
 5. Maybe HomeDrive
 6. UserAccount Controls

I Could do this with follwoing Code:

```
@{label='Username';expression={$_.properties[x].value}},
```

But this would be static and i have to create for every Event a new function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer.

```
$event = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Logname='security';ID=$instanceID} -MaxEvents 1

foreach($entry in $event){
    #Get the XML...
    $XML = [xml]$entry.ToXml()

    #Some events use other nodes, like 'UserData' on Applocker events...
    $XMLData = $null
    if( $XMLData = @( $XML.Event.EventData.Data )) {
        For( $i=0; $i -lt $XMLData.count; $i++ ) {
            #We don't want to overwrite properties that might be on the original object, or in another event node.   
            Add-Member -InputObject $entry -MemberType NoteProperty -name "EventData$($XMLData[$i].name)" -Value $XMLData[$i].'#text' -Force
        }
    }
}

$entry | select EventData*
```

Answer (score 1):

You can as an alternative to your script (approach) attach a Windows task to that event from using the event viewer :

You right click on the event then click on "Attach Task to This Event…". Then you have multiple choices, you can for example run a program (it can be powershell.exe) or send an email.

Reference : https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wincat/2011/08/25/trigger-a-powershell-script-from-a-windows-event/

**UPDATE**

My bad, "sending email from task event" is [deprecated](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/34cdb5de-9e8f-4a8b-8eb7-18dd244a6071/windows-server-2012-event-email-notification-deprecated-really-kidding-right?forum=winserver8gen).

Another alternative is to create the task and run it with "powershell.exe" and pass as argument a script that calls the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
Yes, i know that but its deprecated and not the solution i would like to have :)

Comment: @lukas Can you specify further what kind of solution you were expecting ?

Comment: I had to Answer in a "Add Another Answer"

Comment: 's Update
Yes i would use this but i would like to specify the Subject and Body with like "New User xyz was created by User xyz"
In the body i would write some more detailed and easy to read text

Comment: @lukas in the approach I suggested you have to pass parameters to the ps script which contains `eventrecordID` that you can use to get the event that triggered the task and then fetch the data you want (as you stated in the last update of your question) and send it by email

Answer (score 0):

[This is what WMI Event consumers / watchers are designed for](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-monitor-and-respond-to-events-on-your-server/). You can set [temporary](https://learn-powershell.net/2013/08/02/powershell-and-events-wmi-temporary-event-subscriptions/) or [permanent](https://learn-powershell.net/2013/08/14/powershell-and-events-permanent-wmi-event-subscriptions/) ones.

This is a very common thing and there are examples all over the web as to how to set this up, and even prebuilt scripts you can use as it or tweak as needed.

[Powershell Centralized Log Monitor](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/ed188912-1a20-4be9-ae4f-8ac46cf2aae4)

Monitors a collection of servers for specified log events, and sends email alerts when it encouters the monitored events.

```
## Powershell Log Monitor Script ## 
## Contributing authors - mck74,mjolinor, 

param([switch]$ShowEvents = $false,[switch]$NoEmail = $false,[switch]$useinstanceid = $false) 


$log = "Application" 
$hist_file = $log + "_loghist.xml" 
$seed_depth = 200 

#run interval in minutes - set to zero for runonce, "C" for 0 delay continuous loop. 
$run_interval = 1 

$EmailFrom = "<user@domain.tld>" 
$EmailTo = "<user@domain.tld>" 
$EmailSubject = "Server event notification"   

$SMTPServer = "smtphost.domain.tld" 
$SMTPAuthUsername = "username" 
$SMTPAuthPassword = "password" 

$computers = @(gc monitored_computers.txt) 
$event_list = @{} 
Import-Csv alert_events.csv |% {$event_list[$_.source + '#' + $_.id] = 1} 


#see if we have a history file to use, if not create an empty $histlog 
if (Test-Path $hist_file){$loghist = Import-Clixml $hist_file} 
 else {$loghist = @{}} 


$timer = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew() 

function send_email { 
$mailmessage = New-Object system.net.mail.mailmessage  
$mailmessage.from = ($emailfrom)  
$mailmessage.To.add($emailto) 
$mailmessage.Subject = $emailsubject 
$mailmessage.Body = $emailbody 
$mailmessage.IsBodyHTML = $true 
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 25)   
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("$SMTPAuthUsername", "$SMTPAuthPassword")  
$SMTPClient.Send($mailmessage) 
} 
#START OF RUN PASS 
$run_pass = { 

$EmailBody = "Log monitor found monitored events. `n" 

$computers |%{ 
$timer.reset() 
$timer.start() 

Write-Host "Started processing $($_)" 

#Get the index number of the last log entry 
$index = (Get-EventLog -ComputerName $_ -LogName $log -newest 1).index 

#if we have a history entry calculate number of events to retrieve 
#   if we don't have an event history, use the $seed_depth to do initial seeding 
if ($loghist[$_]){$n = $index - $loghist[$_]} 
 else {$n = $seed_depth} 

if ($n -lt 0){ 
 Write-Host "Log index changed since last run. The log may have been cleared. Re-seeding index." 
 $events_found = $true 
 $EmailBody += "`n Possible Log Reset $($_)`nEvent Index reset detected by Log Monitor`n" | ConvertTo-Html 
 $n = $seed_depth 
 } 

Write-Host "Processing $($n) events." 

#get the log entries 

if ($useinstanceid){ 
$log_hits = Get-EventLog -ComputerName $_ -LogName $log -Newest $n | 
? {$event_list[$_.source + "#" + $_.instanceid]} 
} 

else {$log_hits = Get-EventLog -ComputerName $_ -LogName $log -Newest $n | 
? {$event_list[$_.source + "#" + $_.eventid]} 
} 

#save the current index to $loghist for the next pass 
$loghist[$_] = $index 

#report number of alert events found and how long it took to do it 
if ($log_hits){ 
 $events_found = $true 
 $hits = $log_hits.count 
 $EmailBody += "`n Alert Events on server $($_)`n" 
 $log_hits |%{ 
  $emailbody += "<br><br>" 
  $emailbody += $_ | select MachineName,EventID,Message | ConvertTo-Html  
 $emailbody += "<br><br>" 
 } 
 } 
 else {$hits = 0} 
$duration = ($timer.elapsed).totalseconds 
write-host "Found $($hits) alert events in $($duration) seconds." 
"-"*60 
" " 
if ($ShowEvents){$log_hits | fl | Out-String |? {$_}} 
} 

#save the history file to disk for next script run  
$loghist | export-clixml $hist_file 

#Send email if there were any monitored events found 
if ($events_found -and -not $NoEmail){send_email} 

} 
#END OF RUN PASS 

Write-Host "`n$("*"*60)" 
Write-Host "Log monitor started at $(get-date)" 
Write-Host "$("*"*60)`n" 

#run the first pass 
$start_pass = Get-Date 
&$run_pass 

#if $run_interval is set, calculate how long to sleep before the next pass 
while ($run_interval -gt 0){ 
if ($run_interval -eq "C"){&$run_pass} 
 else{ 
 $last_run = (Get-Date) - $start_pass 
 $sleep_time = ([TimeSpan]::FromMinutes($run_interval) - $last_run).totalseconds 
 Write-Host "`n$("*"*10) Sleeping for $($sleep_time) seconds `n" 

#sleep, and then start the next pass 
 Start-Sleep -seconds $sleep_time 
 $start_pass = Get-Date  
 &$run_pass 
 } 
 }
```